# CSS oddities with Office UI Fabric libraries

Tags: office-js, office365-apps, office-ui-fabric

I'm working on a Word 2016 Add-in project and I'm having some difficulties using Office UI Fabric libraries.

Basically I would like to give my Add-in the official Office look & feel, so I thought that Office UI Fabric would be the best choice, in conjunction with Fabric javascript components, like dropdown menus and so on.

I installed these two NuGet packages: **OfficeUIFabric 2.6.3** and **OfficeUIFabricJS 1.4.0**, then I added some components to a page, by using these css classes: "ms-Dropdown", "ms-ChoiceField" and some icon classes, like "ms-Icon--Settings".

These are the (odd) results I'm having:

- OfficeUIFabric and OfficeUIFabricJS ship two different versions of the same "fabric.components.css" file, so the final result depends on the order on which these two packages are installed.
- with "fabric.components.css" coming from OfficeUIFabric 2.6.3, all icons are missing but ChoiceField is styled correctly.
- with "fabric.components.css" coming from OfficeUIFabricJS 1.4.0, icons are visible, but dropdown button is being drawn outside the rectangular textbox and ChoicheField's style is wrong (the label wraps and checkbox is a standard HTML control).

Do you have any experience with these libraries?
I'm about to switch to a more comfortable framework, like Bootstrap or similar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you have any experience with these libraries?

Yes ;) If this is your question.

> These are the (odd) results I'm having ...

I surprise you are getting any results at all. The issue with incorrect usage of OfficeUIFabric libraries. Let me clarify how team behind planned on the usage of these libraries ...

- [Fabric 2.6.1](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/blob/master/ghdocs/V2GETSTARTED.md) (current latest version is [2.6.3](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/releases/tag/2.6.3)) is last known (stable) version of the package where the Core part (CSS) and components part (JS components) where together. Basically when you install this version, you would use it as is. No need for any other packages. In fact you cannot install on the top Different core version or JS version, you will brake the package integrity (which is that you observe)
- Next development and major release was absolutely different. The package separate "JS components" part and become "[Office UI Fabric Core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core)". this package is nothing else as set of CSS styles to make your custom app look like Office itself. The current Core Package should be used on its own (basically you have ms_ styles to use at your convenience) or in the couple with "[Office UI Fabric JS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js)".
- Finally the new package "[Office UI Fabric JS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js)" is the set of JS components (which used to be included inside 2.6.1 package) should be used when you want to have "styled" components which will look like Office native components. Fabric JS 1.4.0 uses Fabric Core 5.0.1. Probably your next question why is it happen? The old package 2.6.1 has components part based on JQuery; the new one 1.4.0 (weird, ahh? the version is lower) has no dependency on any 3rd party package, written with TypeScript.

I hope this is clarify something for you or someone who puzzled as well. We work with Fabric package I believe from version one and try both 2.6.1 and new 1.4.0+5.0.1. There are a lot of issues, too many things out of order. We cannot afford to spend so much time just to have new slick look. Basically with some tweaks we stopped on 2.6.1 version and will not go with new Fabric at least for now. If I would have luxury to go back and choose again on the UI package, I would not go with Fabric, indeed, instead would use JQuery UI or JQuery Mobile. No offence to Microsoft team, but Fabric team is looks like bunch of teenagers, who is trying their best, but the luck of experience spoil everything. This is not world class software as we used to see from Microsoft.

Comment: Ivanov, I totally agree with you on Fabric chaotic situation. What you're explaining is not so clear on Fabric and Fabric-distribution sites (NuGet project description for OfficeUIFabricJS is saying No dependencies, while it turns out it depends on Core!), thanks for pointing me to the right direction.
But it's not yet fully clear to me. According to what you have explained, my project should reference only the complete package, OfficeUIFabric. But if I do so, all icons and dropdown controls are gone. So it's not so "complete"...

Comment: @jeanie77 You didn't tell clearly what you end up using? Is it 2.6.3 along or JS 1.4.0 + Core 5.0.1? Anyways, you, once again, mix those solutions. 1. if you use 1.4.0+5.0.1 all icons and controls should be in place. If not refer to [documentation](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/styles/icons) or docs included into every component. 2. If you are end up using just 2.6.3 version, clean up your solution from previously installed packages and install it from scratch. To use styles refer **ONLY** to docs included into components and CSS downloaded. Internet resource **not valid** for 2.6.3 ver.

Comment: I tried using only OfficeUIFabric 2.6.3, first cleaning up all Fabric libraries and then adding only 2.6.3 (not from CDN, I used the NuGet package). And I had the reported behaviour: all icons and dropdown were gone.

Comment: Let me add some further details, since Fabric NuGet packages' content is different from what you've written about the three libraries. OfficeUIFabric 2.6.3 package does not include fabric.js, so it cannot include javascript features. OfficeUIFabricJS 1.4.0 package does include styles from Office UI Fabric Core 5.0.1, so it's not necessary to install Core as a separate package.

Comment: @jeanie77 OK, you  want to use 2.6.3 and installed it from NuGet. Excellent! this is what you need, nothing else. Your js file included with this library and it's called "jquery.fabric.js", see it under "Scripts". Do not mess it with any other packages. Just forget they exist. Read documentation supplied with this package (you may need to download entire package from GitHub, unzip it and find examples). For example to display check icon: '<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--check"></i>'

Comment: "fabric.Dropdown is not a constructor", cause it's included only in fabric.js, not jquery.fabric.js. I solved by removing OfficeUIFabric 2.6.3 and keeping only OfficeUIFabricJS 1.4.0. Thanks for your helpfulness! :)

Comment: @jeanie77 I mentioned several times, you **cannot** use online documentation for 2.6.3 version, instead you need to use documentation supplied with the package. Inside, you would find example on "$.fn.Dropdown" element. There is no such thing as "fabric.Dropdown" in this version (this become available in JS 1.0 version). If you want to use online examples and doc, you need to install Fabric JS 1.4.0 + Core 5.01. Hopefully I answered on all your questions. Somebody else may benefit from or discussion if you mark it as answer.

Comment: FYI, `office-ui-fabric` npm package [has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-ui-fabric). The recommended way is to use [office-ui-fabric-core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/) (for basic styles without components) or [office-ui-fabric-react](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react) (no luck for Angular guys). Pure JS library [office-ui-fabric-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) is still available, but it includes an old version of `office-ui-fabric-core`.

Answer (score 1):

What Slava described is correct.

As an alternative, can you reference Fabric from the CDN in your project? If referencing the CDN is an option for you (instead of installing the NuGet packages), then follow this topic to reference Fabric from the CDN:
[Use Office UI Fabric in Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-js)

The files on the CDN have been built together such that the version numbers match. Also, because Fabric JS uses Fabric Core, the correct version of Fabric Core is deployed along with the Fabric JS files. So you don't have to guess which version of Fabric Core should be used with a newer version of Fabric JS.

Comment: I can't use the online version, since I'm building a component that should work without external resources. Anyway, the problem is still understanding which library should be used to see icons and other js components... and whether Fabric JS includes or depends on Core. The online version should follow the same specifications as the offline does, maybe they're different in versions... but nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share my recent experience with the Office Add-in JS libraries.

ATM, there are two ways of developing the front-end part of the Office 365 add-in:

- A ReactJS app with using [office-ui-fabric-react](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react) library. It's a recommended way of building add-ins, as it's an up-to-date project with all proper styles and good components.
- Your own app with CSS/SASS styles from [office-ui-fabric-core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/) (just basic styles, no components). The styles are well documented (see under 'dist/documentation' of the project) and can be a good replacement for Bootstrap/Material UI frameworks, considering that the look of the add-in must obey the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-design).

I do NOT recommend using [office-ui-fabric-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) library in combination with JS frameworks (e.g. Angular, Vue), even if at the first glance it might be appealing (has some components and nice styles). It's an unprofessionally built library (see [this list of problems](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/issues/359)) with CSS from an old version of `office-ui-fabric-core`, and it seems to be abandoned.

In terms of other ways [officially recommended](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric):

- The AngularJS library ([ng-officeuifabric](https://github.com/ngOfficeUIFabric/ng-officeuifabric/)) is officially "[in archive mode](https://github.com/ngOfficeUIFabric/ng-officeuifabric/)". No signs of supporting Angular.
- The [iOS project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-ios) hasn't been updated for 2 years (though, it didn't show much life before).