# Office UI Fabric doesn't render in my Excel Addin project

Tags: office-addins, office-ui-fabric

From VS 2017, I created a new Excel Addin. In `Home.html`, just before `<div class="footer">`, I added the following section from [this Microsoft template](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/ChoiceFieldGroup/ChoiceFieldGroup.html):

```
<div class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup" id="choicefieldgroup" role="radiogroup">
    <div class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-title">
        <label class="ms-Label is-required">Unselected</label>
    </div>
    <ul class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-list">
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input">
            <label role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">Option 1</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input">
            <label role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">Option 2</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input">
            <label role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field is-disabled" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" name="choicefieldgroup" aria-disabled="true">
                <span class="ms-Label">Option 3</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input">
            <label role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">Option 4</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I should notice that I confirm these references are in `Home.html` head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
```

When I run this project, I get in the task pane:

[image]

However, I was expecting this:

[image]

What's wrong with with logic? If I create manually a HTML file with Fabric's CSS and the code template, it renders fine, but that doesn't work in my Excel Addin project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including very old version of the fabric, indeed, but using the example from the website for current version. [Get started](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/GetStarted/GetStarted.html) explains you where to get the [fabric-ui-core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core) (styles) and [fabric-ui-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) (components) to run examples from the website properly.

If you will puzzle yourself why is the included version 2.1.0 is older than 1.4.0 please refer to this explanation: [CSS oddities with Office UI Fabric libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830949/css-oddities-with-office-ui-fabric-libraries/42841039#42841039)

Comment: This is confusing as hell. Your answer helped to solve my problem and now I'll dig into this dark world because I'll insist with Fabric.
Thanks!